# concerning UNION and JOIN in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is my tables:

[image]

how to do I get the following from the above table in mysql using union?

[image]
here is my answer:

```
   SELECT name, city(Person) FROM Persons
   UNION 
   SELECT name, 'something' FROM Persons
   UION
   SELECT pname, city(Project) FROM  Projects;
```

Comment: Would you care to include a question?

Comment: there is a question "how to do I get the following from the above table in mysql using union?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT name, city, 'Person' AS Explanation FROM Persons
UNION ALL
SELECT pname, place, 'Project' AS Explanation FROM Projects
```

Comment: Please avoid posting such comments. You can upvote and accept the answer which is the correct thing to do in case it helped you.